# Detect if IE flash player is installed from a C++ executable

Tags: c++, flash, internet-explorer

I have a Windows app written in C++ and I need to detect if Flash is installed for IE. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few ways to do it.  One way would be to check for the existence of the binary:

1. Use [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28VS.85%29.aspx) with CSIDL_SYSTEM to get the path to the system32 directory.
2. Use [FindFirst/FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see if windows\system32\macromed\flash exists, and specifically a file of the form "flash???.ocx".  Note that the NPSWF32.dll is the Netscape plugin (FF, Chrome) version of Flash, so make sure you look for the ocx.

You can also probably check the registry for something.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=61736
This thread is relevant to your problem. Just do the same in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I check it.

We will be looking in registry. If user performs uninstall then these values are removed.

```
#define FLASH_KEYDIR _T("Software\\Macromedia\\FlashPlayerActiveX")
#define FLASH_KEY _T("PlayerPath")
#define FLASHPLUGIN_KEYDIR _T("Software\\Macromedia\\FlashPlayerPlugin")
#define FLASHPLUGIN_KEY _T("PlayerPath")
```

PlayerPath in both cases contains the full path to ocx/dll, e.g. for ActiveX (IE) version of player it would look like `C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash32_11_3_300_257.ocx` and for plugin version of player it would look like `C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_11_3_300_257.dll`

So what we do is a) checking the registry value and if it exists then b) see if the file exists. Perhaps this would only work for newer Flash packages. I am not sure how this code woudl handle old Flash installations.